# Need help in creating shortcut

Tags: input-language

This is my first time using Ubuntu.

I would like to know how to create a shortcut to change the language that I use to write.

For example, in Windows you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to cycle between languages.

How do I do that in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Could you explain why the title is totally unrelated to the question?

Comment: Sorry I was posting something else on another website and got lost between the posts anyway it is fixed now...sorry.